# Not able to order fill colors as desired

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to produce a plot with two separate geom_area commands, in order to draw some time series above and some below the zero line. Here is a simple example:

```
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")

d <- as.data.frame(t(read.table(sep=";",header=F,row.names=1,text="
year;1999;2000;2001;2002;2003;2004;2005;2006;2007;2008;2009;2010;2011;2012
primary balance;-5.63;-11.88;-15.37;-18.3;-20.09;-21.45;-21.87;-23.25;-26.98;-29.56;-28.92;-28.46;-29.64;-32.61
snow-ball effect;1.61;0.81;2.67;4.99;7.23;8.02;9.45;9.6;11.01;14.06;22.81;24.41;25.76;26.89
adjustment;2.83;5.38;6.52;3.93;2.28;2.45;3.94;5.28;4.5;6.73;6.94;7.59;7.73;8.07")))
dd <- melt(d,id.vars="year")
dd1 <- subset(dd,variable=="primary balance")
dd2 <- subset(dd,variable!="primary balance")
ggplot()+
  geom_area(data=dd1,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=variable,order=variable),alpha=.5)+
  geom_area(data=dd2,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=variable,order=variable),alpha=.5)
```

The plot is:
[image: plot]

Although the order of levels for variable is: (1) "primary balance", (2) "snow-ball effect" and (3) "adjustment", there is now way I can tell ggplot to assign colors and put items in the legend in the correct order.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the order using `scale_fill_manual(values=..., breaks=...)`:

```
ggplot() +
geom_area(data=dd1,
          aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable, order=variable), 
          alpha=.5) +
geom_area(data=dd2,
          aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable, order=variable),
          alpha=.5) +
scale_fill_manual(values=scales::hue_pal()(3),
                  breaks=c("adjustment",
                           "snow-ball effect",
                           "primary balance"))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: To align the legend with the plot, you can also use: `scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("adjustment", "snow-ball effect", "primary balance"))`

Comment: This changes the order in the legend, but I also need to change the order of colors. It should be red-blue-green instead of green-blue-red. I cannot explain the inconsistency between the order used by ggplot and the order of levels

Comment: This is certainly a possibility. Still, this behavior looks weird, and since I need to make colors consistent among a number of plots using the same palette, I'd prefer not to rely on manual setting of colours.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scale_fill_manual` to manually choose colours and decide the ordering in the legend.

```
ggplot()
+geom_area(data=dd1,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=variable,order=variable),alpha=.5)
+geom_area(data=dd2,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=variable,order=variable),alpha=.5)
+scale_fill_manual(values=c("primary balance"="yellow","snow-ball effect" = "violet","adjustment" = "green"),breaks = levels(dd$variable))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an explanation of why it does not automatically assign colors according to the order of variables?

Comment: Assigning colors in `scale_fill_manual` is based on alphabetical ordering for unnamed `values` vector. So you have to name the vector to change the ordering as needed.Refer [http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_manual.html](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_manual.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
dd <- melt(d,id.vars="year")
o <- ordered(c("primary balance","snow-ball effect","adjustment"), c("primary balance","snow-ball effect","adjustment"))
dd$variable <- ordered(dd$variable, o)
dd1 <- subset(dd,variable=="primary balance")
dd2 <- subset(dd,variable!="primary balance")
p <- ggplot()+ geom_area(data=dd1,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=variable), alpha=.5)
p <- p +  geom_area(data=dd2,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=variable), alpha=.5)
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values = setNames(scales::hue_pal()(length(levels(dd$variable))), o),
                           breaks = o)
p
```

Do you want it in that way? The problem is ggplot sorts factors alphabetically. So colors might be changed. With `ordered` you generate a factor and tell how its levels are sorted. 
[image]